# How to Upgrade to ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project. It is .NET Framework based. I have been working with .NET Version 4.6, but am happy to upgrade to 4.6.2 or 4.7. I have both installed on my machine. The referenced NuGet packages are numerous and version numbers varied. But, it seems that roughly speaking, I am using version 1.1.3 of ASP.NET Core.

I want to upgrade to the latest version of ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET Core MVC but every time I try, I get this error message:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.0.0'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

After Googling for this, I came across this disconcerting Github thread:
https://github.com/aspnet/home/issues/2022

This seems to imply that at some point, V2 was not supported by the .NET Framework. I read through the thread to some extent, but these words from another user basically some up my thoughts on the subject:

> I really don't know what is happening. Why do have many dotnet this
>   and that. This is really crazy. How do we have keep tracks of this?
>
> No proper documentation on migration from one to another.

The OP was edited to say this:

> Edit: the "no .NET Framework support for ASP.NET Core 2.0" plan has
>   been officially cancelled and running ASP.NET Core 2.0 on .NET Desktop
>   will be supported in the next previews. For more information, read
>   Announcing ASP.NET Core 2.0.0-Preview1 and Updates for .NET Web
>   Developers or watch .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core 2.0.

I guess that means that Microsoft planned to fix the problem at some point. But, what I can't work out is whether or not Microsoft have actually fixed this problem.

**Is anyone running ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework? Which .NET version? How did you get it working?**

Comment: I'm assuming you have downloaded all the necessary .net core 2 installers? I just created a new project using core 2 and it is running fine on 4.6

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/

Comment: How can I check if I have everything installed correctly? I just installed dotnet-sdk-2.0.2-win-gs-x64.exe again, but it just gave me the option to repair or uninstall so I assume I have it installed.

Comment: @Alexan this article is for .NET Core. In .NET Core, it's simple. You just install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package, but this does not work in .NET Framework.

Comment: Just target .NET Standard 2.0, instead. With .NET Standard 2.0, you can reference virtually any .NET Framework library you might need.

Comment: @chrispratt that's doubtful. We need to serve up WCF. Does .net standard now support serving up WCF?

Comment: @JohanP , you might want to write your suggestion up as answer "I just created a new project using core 2 and it is running fine on 4.6". You were right. I was able to create a new project from scratch. This is going to suck, but it appears that we will be able to create a new project and migrate all the content in to the new project. If it works, you've won the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Melbourne Developer's suggestion:

1. Make sure you download the latest [.Net Core 2.0 installers](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows).
2. Create new ASP.Net Core Web Application
3. Choose .NET Framework from dropdownlist in wizard and ASP.Net Core 2.0
4. Copy content over to new project. Fixing up all namespace issues/compilation errors

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was Download the latest .Net Core 2.0 installers -> Create a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 - .NET Framework Project -> Migrate old content in to new project. Along the way, they will need to fix up broken namespaces and references that Microsoft have changed.

Comment: My bad, fixed it up